# Pgadmin>Tools>IMPORT/EXPORT Grayed out | Cannot use it to export servers

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I need to centralise a Pgadmin instance for multiple Envs
so I need to EXPORT/IMPORT them to the new Pgadmin

My problem is i cannot use the IMPORT/EXPORT dialog in Tools as it's grayed out

[image]

Ps: i can use it to import/ex tables but not servers && i have admin rights on my pgadmin

tried the "setup.py --dump-servers output_file.json" command without success as pg is in a pod

Comment: What is your pgadmin version, my version is 6.12 and there is "server export" option.

Comment: Hello sami lekesiz , pgadmin4 but when i go to 'about pgadmin4' tab it says version5 sorry i'm new :)

Comment: you should update your pgadmin.
https://www.pgadmin.org/download/

Comment: Yes, that is what that choice under tool does, import or export tables.  You will need to choose a different entry under tools to do something different.  Also, you need to upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, i need to update my pgadmin                                                        @jjanes i know but i can also Import/Export the servers (not just the tables), in my case that's what i'm strugelling with, anyway will try to update to recent version :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in 6.x version, I upgraded to 8.x version and now I can export the connection settings as json and import in the other machine.